# PHP file not working on webhosting service

Tags: php, web-hosting

This is my code (sorry for ill formatted code. I'm newbie to web development)

```
<html>
<head>

  <?php
  if (isset($_POST['login']))
  {
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $pass = $_POST['pass'];
    $server='localhost';
    $dbuser = 'database username';
    $dbpass = 'database password';
    $dbname = 'database name';
  // Create connection
  $conn = new mysqli($server, $dbuser, $dbpass, $dbname)
  $sql = "INSERT INTO table (email, password)
  VALUES ('$email','$pass')";
  if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE)
  {
  header('Location: address');
  }

  $conn->close();
  }
  ?>

</head>
<body>

<form method="post" action="index.php">
 email:<br>
 <input type="text" name="email"><br>
 password:<br>
 <input type="password" name="pass"><br>
 <input type = "submit" name="login" value="login">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

I have saved this file as `index.php` in public_html and when I open my hosted website URL, it shows a blank page. Why?

Comment: Because you have PHP syntax error ! add ";" after : $conn = new mysqli($server, $dbuser, $dbpass, $dbname) !

Comment: @Soheyl It worked. Now I'm getting another issue. After clicking on login button, the page is not redirecting to another location (header in php). why?

Comment: use exit(); after header header('Location: https://www.dileepsankhla.wordpress.com'); exit();

Comment: Add else to see if you get "true" !

Comment: turn error reporting on..

Comment: @Soheyl Yes it is going to else part. What is the issue?

Comment: I think you have MySQL connection error ! check if you can connect to your MySQL database by using phpmyadmin ! and then check if you have any data inserted !

Comment: @Soheyl I have issue in this line -   $sql = "INSERT INTO hack (email, password) VALUES ('$email','$pass')";      May you check my code here?

Comment: @Soheyl should I use mysqli or mysql?

Comment: remove ' around variables in your query !

Comment: None ! you should learn to use PDO !

Comment: @Soheyl Thank you so much. It worked :)

Comment: NP and good luck :)

Comment: @dlpnewbie96 you have to use `mysqli_connect()` for connection their is nothing like `mysqli()` for connection.